# Eager load only first associations with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, eager-loading

I have a `User` model and a `:friends` association

When I create the data, I take the user and its first 5 friends

I could do

```
User.includes(:friends)
```

but that will take all friends.

Is there a way to take only the first 5 friends?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the following could work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friends
  has_many :top_friends, -> { limit(5).order(:id) }, class_name: Friend
end

User.includes(:top_friends)
```

Comment: If you eager load an association with a specified :limit option, it will be ignored, returning all the associated objects. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html
In my experience order is also ignored.